# Python, изменение массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Python, необходимо перевести одномерный массив в многомерный по определённому символу, например(допустим по символу 'n'):

Было:

```
['255', '123', '15', 'n', '233', '109', '45', 'n', '10', '89', '3']
```

Стало:

```
[['225', '123', '15'], ['233', '109', '45'], ['10', '89', '3']]
```

Причем, надо, чтобы можно было переводить по любому количеству разделителей (n)

Comment: "надо" и "необходимо" не являются вопросами. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

некрасивый вариант в лоб с возможностью некорректной работы из-за данных несоответствующих типов (не строки):

```
data = ['255', '123', '15', 'n', '233', '109', '45', 'n', '10', '89', '3']

res = [[i for i in obj.split(',') if i != ''] for obj in ','.join(data).split('n')]

print(res)
```

корректное решение в лоб:

```
data = ['255', '123', '15', 'n', '233', '109', '45', 'n', '10', '89', '3']

res = []
tmp = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] == 'n':
        if tmp != []:
            res.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(data[i])

if tmp != []:
    res.append(tmp)

print(res)
```

чуть-чуть покороче решение:

```
res = []
tmp = []

for obj in data:
    if obj == 'n':
        res += [tmp] if tmp else []
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(obj)

res += [tmp] if tmp else []
```

ну и пока самый короткий и немного извращённый вариант, который пришел в голову:

```
res, tmp = [], []

for obj in data:
    res, tmp = (res + [tmp] if tmp else [], []) if obj == 'n' else (res, tmp + [obj])

res += [tmp] if tmp else []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def n2_list(arr, ch):
    res = []
    tmp = []
    for x in arr:
        if x != ch:
            tmp.append(x)
        else:
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp = []
    else:
        res.append(tmp)
    return res

arr = ['255', '123', '15', 'n', '233', '109', '45', 'n', '10', '89', '3']
ch = 'n'
print(n2_list(arr, ch))
```

'>>>[['255', '123', '15'], ['233', '109', '45'], ['10', '89', '3']]